# Why is this sumproduct formula not working?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-drive, google-spreadsheets

I have a sheet that I need the greatest value between two columns, if they equal only count one and the number has to be >2.9
This is what I have so far:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C13:C46<D13:D46)*(D13:D46>2.9))
```

The issue is it will only count column D even if the cell next to it in column C meets the requirements. 
The number in the picture should be 2 not 1.

[image: Sheet Photo]

Comment: The formula did not paste correct.  =SUMPRODUCT((C13:C46<D13:D46)*(D13:D46>2.9)) is what I have now.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please use the **[edit]** link below your question to update it instead of adding comments here. Also, this is a little difficult to understand. Please clarify things like how the data is laid out and whether this is Excel (on topic) or Google Spreadsheets (off topic). Reading thru **[ask]** can be helpful to understand how this site works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this will return what you want:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((C13:C46>2.9)+(D13:D46>2.9)>0)*1)
```

This will find if either is above 2.9 and only count 1 if both are.

Comment: @DougGreek please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer. It is something only you can do.